# Communication between iOS app to MacOS app

Tags: ios, swift, macos, http, websocket

I'm an iOS developer and I want to make an MacOS / OSX application to save files onto the Macbook hard drive that are sent via the internet / wifi from my iPhone, but I haven't got the faintest idea what to research / google when it comes to this.

The three phases as I see them are

1. Create files on iPhone (Done)
2. Some transport / network / server layer on OSX app for iPhone to connect to
3. Storing of files by OSX app...

1 and 3 are pretty straightforward but 2 I don't have a clue... where do I start? socket / server / Apple api.. what should I be searching for?

Apologies in advance... I know the usual community rules about posting broad questions, but I'm completely stuck.

I'll delete the question if it's deemed unworthy, but I'd really love to know if I'm completely barking up the wrong tree / whether there's a really simple solution.

Comment: Why don't you just use AirDrop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that I'd recommend to do this.

- [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store the files and access them on each device.
- [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) instead of S3.
- [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/) can also be used to store information like you can in CoreData.

You don't need any sort of API or backend experience to use any of these, so this may be the best bet for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i would vote for CloutKit because then it is in the normal toolchain of apple and saved on a per user basis by apple (with no cost for you for stuff the user save). and you hassle with authentifiaction/authorization. 

for the other services (Amazon/Firebase) you need to pay for the storage of the user userdata and neet to implement more

Comment: You can also set up a direct TCP/Bonjour link between the two devices and transmit messages over the socket. This way you don't need a backend at all

Comment: OK that makes sense for file access... if I wanted to trigger some task on my macbook when the transfer is complete? I'm thinking along the lines of having the files saved into specific directories on the macbook itself and running some local methods on the files to produce another file.

Comment: Not sure what you're meaning, but I agree with pbush25 that if you only need to communicate between macOS and iOS then you can create a local Bonjour connection. Then you can message back and forth between each OS.

Comment: dont apple require  a secure connection? then it becomes complicated

Comment: I think I've confused things by being too specific with the file transfer bit. I'm aiming along the lines of the Remote app.. where you can use your phone to control the iTunes on your Macbook. From this discussion Bonjour I'm guessing is the way forward?

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer for the file sharing. Thanks for all your efforts guys.